# How do you fill patterns in MonoMac

Tags: cgcontext, monomac

Does anybody know how to fill patterns in MonoMac, this code does nothing unfortunately. It doesn't even call draw pattern. Any help would be awesome :D

```
    void DrawPattern (CGContext NewContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Pattern?");
        NewContext.SetFillColor(new CGColor(1,0,0));
        NewContext.FillRect(new RectangleF(0,0,5,5));
    }
    public void FillPatternPath (CGContext MyCanvas,CGPath Path)
    {
        MyCanvas.SaveState();
        CGPath NewPath=Path.GetCGPath ();
        MyCanvas.AddPath (NewPath);
        RectangleF PBounds=MyCanvas.GetPathBoundingBox();
        MyCanvas.EOClip();
        CGColorSpace patternSpace = CGColorSpace.CreatePattern(null);
        MyCanvas.SetFillColorSpace(patternSpace);
        CGPattern Pat=new CGPattern(PBounds,CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity(),10,10,CGPatternTiling.ConstantSpacing,true,new CGPattern.DrawPattern(DrawPattern));
        MyCanvas.SetFillPattern(Pat,new float[]{1f});
        MyCanvas.FillRect (PBounds);
        patternSpace.Dispose();
        MyCanvas.RestoreState();
```

}

Comment: Ignore this line for a start, sorry. CGPath NewPath=Path.GetCGPath ();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the end by drawing the pattern in a clipped area using a simple for{} routine. I never managed to get CGPattern to work.